# g++ malloc error when linking with libmx and using std::stringstream

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, mex, stringstream

The simplest example is the following program, linked with libmx (`-lmx`) (for MATLAB support) on OS X Yosemite, compiled with g++4.9.1 from macports:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    // ostr << " "; // if I un-comment this line no more malloc error
}
```

I realized that at `ostr` destruction (just before exiting the program), I get a malloc runtime error of the form:

```
testcpp(5362,0x7fff7d2af300) malloc: *** error for object 0x1055b6270: 
pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

If, on the other hand, I uncomment the second line in `main()` and write something to the `ostringstream`, then the program exits happily with no more error. This happens only with g++, clang++ compiles and runs it without any problems. Anyone knows if this is a `g++`-related issue or a `libmx` one?

PS: if I am not using `-lmx` flag on linking, then there is no more malloc error.

Comment: How odd.. It probably doesn't matter, but why are you linking to `libmx` in a file in which you do not include any Matlab library, and in which there is no `mexFunction`? Could you try including `mex.h` perhaps, and put this after your main to check `void mexFunction( int nargout, mxArray *out[], int nargin, const mxArray *in[] ){ main(); }`?

Comment: No no, in my program I include them, but this was just the minimal example in which the bug appears. I am using it to save Eigen matrices into MATLAB format, and to be able to load them back from the .mat file. The full source code (way to large to be posted here) is on https://github.com/vsoftco/qpp and the file where I use the MATLAB functions is https://github.com/vsoftco/qpp/blob/master/include/matlab.h  And the bug appears whenever I use a function called `disp` in https://github.com/vsoftco/qpp/blob/master/include/io.h , where an `ostringstream` is being used for formatting

Comment: @Sh3ljohn can you reproduce the bug?

Comment: So, no, but because I can't link to `-lmx`. I installed the MCR from [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/mcr/), and linked with `-L/path/to/runtime/glnxa64` (I'm on Linux), is that equivalent?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn, Thanks, I'm not sure, will try and let you know. I used the libmx from my MATLAB (R2014b) installation.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I've now linked with the MCR libraries, and still the same bug (I've used the latest MCR, 2014b, will try some other versions). Are you getting any error on Linux?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn The bug appears only in the 2014b version, I've tried MCR 2013b and it works fine. So I guess there is a glitch in the latest version. Not sure if it is solely related to g++ or OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's better to comment on this separately. As I said, I'm having troubles reproducing your error. I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 64 bits with g++ 4.8.2 and I downloaded the [Matlab Compiler Runtime](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/mcr/) v83 and v84 for Linux 64 bits.

The source I am compiling is the following:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    // ostr << " "; // if I un-comment this line no more malloc error
}
```

And the following commands run fine (2014 a and b):

```
g++ -L/opt/MATLAB/MCR/v83/runtime/glnxa64 -Wall malloc_gcc_matlab.cpp -o malloc_gcc_matlab && ./malloc_gcc_matlab
g++ -L/opt/MATLAB/MCR/v84/runtime/glnxa64 -Wall malloc_gcc_matlab.cpp -o malloc_gcc_matlab && ./malloc_gcc_matlab
```

Comment: Ok, thanks much, it's probably a combination among OS X/g++/libmx that produces the fault. It also appears only in R2014b. My guess is that it is related to g++ (I have g++4.9.1), as clang++ runs it fine.

Comment: I think this is a gcc vs. clang issue on OSX (most likely has to do with libstdc++ vs. libc++). For what it's worth, the supported compiler is Apple's Xcode, so you might have to change MEX compilation options if you want to use GCC: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html?sec=maci64

Comment: @Amro, thanks! It is somewhat unfortunate, as clang++ doesn't yet support openmp